# GraphQL Subscriptions on React Native App

Tags: react-native, graphql, apollo-client

I have a React Native mobile app that is using Apollo Client to run subscriptions against a Hasura GraphQL backend. Whilst the app is in the foreground everything is working perfectly, but after about an hour being in the background it looks like the connection to the GraphQL server is being dropped.

Is there a best practise for dealing with this, is there a way to pause a subscription when we go into the background and resume when we come back to the foreground?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you set your WebsocketLink to reconnect = true when adding it to the ApolloClient setup.

```
const wsLink = new WebSocketLink({
  ...,
  options: {
    ...,
    reconnect: true,
  },
});
```

This will ensure that your client reconnects if it loses contact with your server for any reason.